# Perl file upload. How to access filehandle multiple times?

Tags: perl, upload, filehandle

I am trying to detect if uploaded file is a valid UTF-8 and only after that do some operations with its content. It detects non-UTF-8 files ok, but if file is a valid UTF-8 there is no content to process. There is no data to process in a `while(){}` loop. Where is my mistake?

```
use utf8;
use CGI qw(:all -utf8);
use Encode;

my $q           = new CGI;

my $file        = $q->param('importfile');
my $file_handle = $q->upload('importfile');
my $fhtest      = do {
        local $/;
        <$file_handle>;
};

my $utf8;
eval { $utf8 = decode( "utf8", $fhtest, Encode::FB_CROAK ) };
if ($@) {
        die 'Not a valid UTF-8 file';
}

binmode $file_handle, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
while (<$file_handle>) {
        chomp();
        # my code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `readline` (aka `<$fh>`), you read the next line after where you left off. You left off at the end of the file.

Sure, you might be able to use `seek` to rewind the file handle (assuming it's not a pipe), but why would you want to read from the file again? You already have the whole thing in memory, and it's already decoded too! Just split it into lines.

```
 my $file_contents; { local $/; $file_contents = <$file_handle>; }

utf8::decode($file_contents)
   or die 'Not a valid UTF-8 file';

for (split /^/m, $file_contents, -1) {
    chomp;
    ...
}
```

Or since you're chomping anyway,

```
for (split /\n/, $file_contents) {
    ...
}
```

I avoided `do` as it causes an extra copy of the file to be created in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You've already read the entire filehandle in your first loop when you create `$fhtest`. If you want to go back to the beginning, you can use [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html):

```
use Fcntl ':seek';    # import constants
...
my $fhtest      = do {
        local $/;
        <$file_handle>;
};

my $utf8;
eval { $utf8 = decode( "utf8", $fhtest, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC) };
if ($@) {
        die 'Not a valid UTF-8 file';
}

seek $file_handle, 0, SEEK_SET;

# now you can start over with $file_handle
```

Of course, since you've already loaded all the data into memory in `$fhtest`, you could just `split` it on newlines (or whatever) and loop over the results. Or you could open a fake filehandle to what you already have in memory:

```
open my $fake_fh, '<', \$fhtest;
while( <$fake_fh> ) { 
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method with a `seek` works fine. Tried the second one opening a fake filehandle - no data to process in a `while` loop. Thats stratnge, `$fhtest` does contains data but somehow it is not passed to a fake filehandle.

Comment: Using `Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC` fixes that issue. Fixed.